# Apache 2.2 mod-vhost-alias with multiple document roots

Tags: debian, hosting, apache-2.2

I’m a beginner in working with apache and in need of your help. 
My task is to build a dynamic webserver (Debian 6.0.4, Apache 2.2, one public IP) which can host multiple websites and files (like pictures, pdf etc.) for preview purposes.

Now my problem is that I need two different document roots. One for the websites and the other one for the files.

My attempt is to use mod-vhost-alias, so I don’t need a new entry in the httpd.conf for every virtual host.

My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
UseCanonicalName Off
NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.45
<VirtualHost preview.example.com>
    Servername      *. preview.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot     /srv/www/%1/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost websites. preview.example.com >
   Servername      *.websites. preview.example.com
   VirtualDocumentRoot     /srv/www/websites/%1/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

The first vhost serves the files and works fine. The second one should provide directories containing website data. The websites underneath the subdomain “websites” are only reachable, if I deactivate the first virtual host.

What do I have to do, to make both of them work at the same time?

If this topic is already dealt with please give me a link.

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ServerAlias` instead of `ServerName` for the wildcard entries.  `ServerName` doesn't support wildcards.  But, you still should have a `ServerName` set.

Your `<VirtualHost>` definitions also need to match ***exactly*** to your `NameVirtualHost` directive.

Something along these lines:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.45:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.45:80>
    ServerAliast preview-vhost
    ServerName *.preview.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/%1/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.45:80>
    ServerAlias websites-vhost
    ServerName *.websites.preview.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/websites/%1/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi Shane, thank you for your quick help! I followed your advises but I still can't reach any website from the second vhost. I always get a Error 404. What do you think of using two different ip addresses or two different webservers for the vhosts?

Comment: @Larry You could also do that, but there's really no reason that it shouldn't work just fine like this.  Can you provide the output of `apache2ctl -S`?  That should give us a good idea of what's going wrong.